# Our prayer will be accepted or not if a na_mehram come and we offering our prayer?

Tags: salat, non-mahram

If we are praying at our home and our cousins those are na_mehram for us. In that case our prayer (salat) will be accepted or not ? What should we do in that case?

Comment: What is the relation between the validity of a prayer and being seen by others? In the musalla (location where 'Id prayer is performed) in the earlier mosques (before women and men were separated) and in al-Masjid al-Haram one may pray and be seen by non-mahrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prayer of a woman does not invalidate if a man see her, even if they are non-mahrams.

However, it is forbidden for a non-mahram to enter to  women in their own places because of fear of Temptation [`Fitnah`] except for extreme needs.